# How to get first non-null item in list

Tags: python

How would I grab the following:

```
l=[None, None, 'hello', 'hello']
first(l) ==> 'hello'

l = [None, None, None, None]
first(l) ==> None
```

I could try doing it with a list comprehension, but that would then error if it had no items.

Comment: You could iterate using a while loop. Something like: While not None idx += 1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the following:

```
first = next((el for el in your_list if el is not None), None)
```

This builds a gen-exp over `your_list` and then tries to retrieve the first value that isn't `None`, where no value is found (it's an empty list/all values are None), it returns `None` as a default (or change that for whatever you want).

If you want to make this to a function, then:

```
def first(iterable, func=lambda L: L is not None, **kwargs):
    it = (el for el in iterable if func(el))
    if 'default' in kwargs:
        return next(it, kwargs[default])
    return next(it) # no default so raise `StopIteration`
```

Then use as:

```
fval = first([None, None, 'a']) # or
fval = first([3, 4, 1, 6, 7], lambda L: L > 7, default=0)
```

etc...

Comment: The `first` is a function, right?

Comment: Well, it can be made into a function

Comment: `next(filter(None, [None, None, 'a', 'b', 'c']))`

Answer (score 2):

If Im understanding the question correctly

```
l = [None, None, "a", "b"]

for item in l:
    if item != None:
        first = item
        break

print first
```

Output:

`a`

Comment: How is `b` the **first**? :p

Comment: My mistake. It outputs the first. haha